# Python Slicing from the last space till end of string

Tags: python, string, slice

I have a string variable, something like

`new_str = "8. [confusing] use python skills to slice -AB1 +AB2 +AAB"`.

I want to slice from the last letter till the end of the string. The last letter in this case should be `e` from the the word `slice` so the resulting string should be `-AB1 +AB2 +AAB` but I am not sure how to do so.

I have tried this approach `new_str[new_str.rfind(' ') : ]`
but it slices from the last space and returns `+AAB`.

It would be great if someone could help me with this.

Comment: It's not clear to me where you want to start, what is the "last letter"?

Comment: Is the `8. [confusing]` included in your string? Or does it start at `use python ..`?

Comment: You need to have a unique marker based on the meaning of the data.  What makes your string unique within the data?  You say "the last letter", but the last letter is the very last character ("B").  With that said, you can split on spaces or look for a token (like "slice ").  But, without knowing the data here, it's hard to say.  Please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, without knowing more about the meaning of the data.

`new_str.split()[-3:]`

If you need a string, use:

`' '.join(new_str.split()[-3:])`

Answer (score 0):

The reason its printing out +AAB is because the rfind method finds the last occurrence of the specified character, which in this case is the space just before +AAB.

Instead you could do the following:

```
new_str = "8. [confusing] use python skills to slice -AB1 +AB2 +AAB"
print(new_str[new_str.rfind("-"):])
```

Output:

```
-AB1 +AB2 +AAB
```